# How to close mobile app programmatically using IONIC 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

How to close the mobile app programmatically using IONIC 5? Use case: Upon app start, I am displaying a Terms of Use popover and if the user does not accept, I need to close the app. I am using IONIC5+Angular.

Thank you.

V

Comment: `navigator['app'].exitApp();` I did it by this

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work for me. Are you able to share a bit more of the code?

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076048/how-can-i-close-an-ionic-5-app-from-code

Comment: I did. It does work for Android, but not for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

While `navigator['app'].exitApp()` works for Android, it does not work for iOS. Also, according to Apple, the apps should not terminate themselves. For my app, I will just display the "Accept" but. The user will need to close the app manually if they don't want to agree to the Terms of Use.

Answer (score 1):

navigator['app'].exitApp();

**that's work for me **

you also use

@capacitor/app

App.exitApp();

Force exit the app. This should only be used in conjunction with the backButton handler for Android to exit the app when navigation is complete.

Ionic handles this itself so you shouldn’t need to call this if using Ionic.

Answer (score 1):

HTML :-

```
<ion-button color="danger" (click)="close()" fill="clear" expand="block">Close App </ion-button>
```

TS :-

***import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';***

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) { }
```

```
close(){
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe( () => {
      navigator['app'].exitApp();
      })
  }
```