# i want to close the ionic application through button click event but not able to do in ionic 7

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

IONIC version 7.1.1
Cordova version 11.0.0

i have tried the below solution but not working in ionic/angular using cordova

navigator['app'].exitApp();

please any one know how to close the application programmatically

Thank You in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61076048/how-can-i-close-an-ionic-5-app-from-code

Comment: i have try this solution but not working with cordova.with latest ionic version. its working in ionic 5